# Необходимо реализовать вывод данных о пациентах по нескольким методам с помощью LINQ и LINQ запросы

Tags: c#, list, linq

Дан класс Patient.

```
class Patient
{
    public String Name;
    public String Surname;
    public int age;
    public String status;

    public Patient(string Name, string Surname, int age, string status)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Surname = Surname;
        this.age = age;
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Даны пациенты в виде объектов класса Patient. Я их сразу перевел в List для работы с LINQ.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var patients = new List<Patient>()
        {
            new Patient ("Alex", "Mitchel", 21, "critical"),
            new Patient ("Kate", "Pupsvel", 18, "critical"),
            new Patient ("Georgy", "Robbinson", 42, "normal"),
            new Patient ("LG", "Company", 120, "normal"),
            new Patient ("Mikky", "Mouse", 30, "critical")
        };
    }
}
```

Необходимо реализовать вывод данных по 4 методам. Один из них LessThen(пользователь вводит число, а метод выводит всех пациентов младше этого числа:

```
class Methods
{
    static void LessThan()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter age to sort in descending order from this number");
        int number = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var lessThen = from people in patients
                       where people.age < number
                       select people;
        foreach (var person in lessThen)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{person.Name} {person.Surname}");
        }
    }
}
```

Естественно в выражении "from people in patients" метод не видит List  patients.

Как мне реализовать этот метод в Main, чтобы я мог вызывать его и он выполнял мои команды, которые я прописал с применением операторов LINQ в контексте этого метода?

Comment: `Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы методы заработали?` передать в методы `patients`?

Comment: Вы меня спрашиваете? Или я сам на свой вопрос ответил? Мне нужно, чтобы контекст, описанный во втором окне, был вставлен в рамки метода и этот метод вызывался в Main. Потому что сейчас это работающий код, если его просто написать в Main методе. Я поэтому сюда и пишу, потому что не пойму как передать List pations в каждый из методов.

Comment: и то и другое. Вы объявляете patients в одном методе, а пытаетесь его использовать в другом. Другой метод вообще ничего не знает про остальные методы, ему до лампочки что там было объявлено в каком то другом методе. Другими словами, методы не видят локальных переменных других методов.

Comment: Это я понимаю, это видно невооружённым глазом, что никто про этот List не знает у себя. Так как их сделать знающими?

Comment: см мой первый комментарий

Comment: Слушайте, я задал конкретный вопрос, по-моему достаточно подробно описал свою проблему. Если Вам трудно дать ответ или помочь(а этот сайт и создан для этого), то не пишите. Вы с высоты своего опыта прописали мне воду прописных истин. А меня интересует конкретика, а не вода! Давайте еще раз, как передать в методы patients?

Comment: Вы думаете, что задаёте конкретный вопрос. Но на самом деле я ваш вопрос не понимаю. Вы же в курсе сами о том, что у методов есть параметры? И что можно вызвать метод и эти параметры указать? Судя по комментам, в курсе. Может вы просто покажете что вы пытаетесь и поясните, что там не работает?

Comment: Как Вам будет удобнее показать?

Comment: дв просто ваш код вставьте в вопрос и поясните, что в нем не работает

Comment: Я переписал более подробно. Прошу прощения за эмоциональность. Я просто со вчерашнего вечера понять не могу как мне передать этот List методу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как пример

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var patients = new List<Patient>()
        {
            new Patient ("Alex", "Mitchel", 21, "critical"),
            new Patient ("Kate", "Pupsvel", 18, "critical"),
            new Patient ("Georgy", "Robbinson", 42, "normal"),
            new Patient ("LG", "Company", 120, "normal"),
            new Patient ("Mikky", "Mouse", 30, "critical")
        };
        
        Methods.LessThan(patients);
    }
}

class Methods
{
    public static void LessThan(List<Patient> patients)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter age to sort in descending order from this number");
        int number = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var lessThen = from people in patients
                       where people.age < number
                       select people;
        foreach (var person in lessThen)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{person.Name} {person.Surname}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за терпение и за помощь. Я тоже прописывал аргументом List в методе, вот только в Main я почему-то обращался не через класс к методу(как показано у Вас), а через экземпляр класса, который я зачем-то создавал. Все работает.

Comment: Можно сделать и через экземпляр, только метод тогда не должен быть статическим. Если помогло, то галочка слева от ответа